# Как правильно разделить js-код?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Возникла необходимость разбить js-код по нескольким файлам, так как некоторый код используется не на всех страницах сайта. Выделил main.js, собственные плагины banner.js и carousel.js. И вот с последним возникла проблема. Каждый файл имеет следующую обертку:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* тут какой-то код */
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Последовательность подключения файлов:

banner.js

carousel.js

main.js

Дело в том, что в main.js используется функция из carousel.js, но мне выдает ошибку, что такая функция не определена. Я убрал выше приведенную обертку у carousel.js и ошибка перестала возникать, но теперь плагин вообще перестал работать, так как из-за отстутствия $(document).ready() он не находит нужные элементы на странице.

Как правильно организовать структуру и подключение файлов в моем случае?

Comment: @andreyqin, 

    (function(){...})()

Называется замыканием, и ничего из замыкания нельзя достать, пока замыкание это не возвращает или не объявляет в глобальной области видимости (`window.func = function(arg){...}`). Надо либо объявлять все в одном замыкании, либо выносить в `window` общие куски.

Comment: ну вообще если carousel.js - jqeury плагин, то должно работать, почему не работает... наверное не плагин.

Comment: вообще - на будущее, можно писать, когда делаете ready вот так:

    jQuery(function($){
     /*код*/
    });

без доп внешнего замыкания

Comment: @eicto, carousel.js - это самописный плагин.
На данный момент сделал следующее в carousel.js: объявил глобальные переменные, соответствующие названиям функций, в самом начале, перед оберткой, а внутри обертки присвоил этим переменных необходимые функции. Понимаю, что с глобальными переменными - не очень хорошее решение, но по другому не получается.
Были еще варианты реализовать паттерн "Модуль", объявить пространство имен или использовать RequireJS, но из-за отсутствия хороших знаний языка, реализовать не получилось.

Comment: @Fike, это же вроде называется анонимная функция или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @andreyqin, там больше, чем анонимная функция, скажем так. Чисто алгоритмически создается и тут же выполняется анонимная функция.

Comment: @andreyqin, у jquery уже все готово для написания собственных плагинов без проблем с областями видимости. Там документации-то на десять минут может быть.

Comment: @andreyqin jquery плагин объявляется примерно так:

    (function($) {
      $.fn.pluginName=function() {
      }
    })(jQuery);

и вызывается примерно так `$(selector).pluginName()`

без этого это не плагин вовсе. больше читайте [здесь](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)

Comment: @eicto, в таком случае это не плагин, а просто самописная карусель. Внутри определяются необходимые переменные и несколько функций.

Comment: @andreyqin, вам шашечки или ехать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, вы созрели для [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/) (на англ.), [пост на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/152833/).

Comment: Да мне бы что-нибудь попроще, у меня же не большое веб-приложение, а обычный сайтик. Пока что использую глобальные переменные для функций, хотя понимаю, что решение не очень хорошее.

Comment: @andreyqin, тем лучше, что новые технологии не надо внедрять на пышащей жаром кузнице контента.

Answer (score 1):

Инкапсулируйте свой код:

```
var initBanner = function() {
   /* some js */
}

var initCarousel = function() {
   /* some js */
}

var initSome = function() {
   /* some js */
}
```

Разделите хоть на 10 js файлов, а далее прямо в футере объявляйте

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    initSliders();              // all sliders init
    initMaps();                 // maps and markers initialising
    initTabs();                 // init tabs
    planingModule();            // Module: room planing

});

$(window).load(function(){

    initBanner();           // arrows slide up
    initCarousel();         // circle progress bar

});

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

весь js код сливай в один файлик и сжимай например с помощью yuicompressor. по нескольким файлам не разбивай это лишнее,js все равно в браузере кэшируется

Comment: шмяк шмяк и в продакшен

Comment: как раз таки чтобы слить весь js в один файлик, нужно задать очередность, а это уже дополнительная гарантия того, что на какой-нибудь странице что-нибудь не отвалится

Comment: js закешируется в браузере и будет храниться на стороне клиента, для js и css я использую жесткое кэширование на 1 год, когда нужно обновить версию в кэше меняю название файликов all.v-0.2.js и тд, и весь этот процесс автоматизирован через phing

Comment: Как минимум не удобно вносить изменения в большом файле

Comment: большой файл на продакшене генерируется из мелких автоматически